# Cannot target .NET Framework 4.7.2 in VS 2017 15.7.5

Tags: visual-studio, .net-framework-version

I have installed .NET Framework 4.7.2 from [Microsoft's website](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-framework-runtime).  However, when I'm in Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.7.5 (currently the latest)) I cannot target Framework 4.7.2 even though it is installed on the computer.  All other Frameworks are there.

[image: Target Framework]

When running the Visual Studio installer there is only the option to install up to 4.7.1.

[image: VS Installer frameworks]

Does VS 2017 15.7.5 literally not support targetting project to 4.7.2 yet or what might be going on here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For *developing* with .NET Framework 4.7.2, the .NET Framework **Dev Pack** must be installed, not just the runtime.

Currently it can be found at [Download .NET Framework 4.7.2](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net472), but that location is likely to change in future.